# Scrolling Images From NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I parse an XML in my blog app.  When I parse it, I have created an object called entry, with properties for Title, Article, Link, Content, and Image.  I then have a mutable array called entries that after parsing is finished, I add to entries the object entry.  This way, to get the Title of a certain article in a tableview, I can call

```
 RSSEntry *entry = [_Entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString *title = entry.Title;
```

What I would like to do is have a UIImageView above the tableview, and set that to scroll through all the different UIImages in the array, but am unsure of how to accomplish this.  I know of the animationImages property, but not sure what to set as the NSArray in all this, since I use Mutable Array with properties.  Any suggestions would greatly help.

Comment: You mean not scrolling but showing the images one by one, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

a) collect all the images in the separate array by iterating through `_Entries` to set the `animationImages` array value;

b) prepare your own view, initialize the timer at constructor with `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]`, change the displayed image at `selector`. To make a smooth animation you can use two imageView subviews setting **animated** the displayed imageView alpha from 1 to 0 and the next imageView alpha from 0 to 1. As the datasource you can use array of `RSSEntry*` taking the images from there with a known keypath.

The first option is fairly easier.

Comment: I tried doing this, but keep getting an error that objectAtIndex:0 beyond bounds for empty array.  Am trying ~RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:0];

    loadingimages = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:entry.forScroll];~ just to test it out, but for some reason the array is coming back empty, even though it is just fine on table view's indexpath.row

Comment: But you are not creating array of `UIImage*`, use `loadingimages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIImage alloc]initWithImage:entry.forScroll], nil];` where you can add more images before `nil`. Than you assign `imageView.animationImages = loadingimages; [imageView startAnimating];`

Comment: the error about the index being outside of bounds of empty array is coming on RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: Well I'm not sure that must be `_allEntries`, that was my assumption based on the code you posted. But it works for the table view delegate, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how to put the UIImageView above the tableview in the xob/storyboard.
Than I am not sure what would you like to do with array of images, but if that mets your needs than it can be a swipe recognizer, and swipe the images

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* recognizerLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];

    recognizerLeft.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    recognizerLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired =1;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizerLeft];
    [recognizerLeft release];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer* recognizerRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];

    recognizerRight.direction =UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    recognizerRight.numberOfTouchesRequired =1;

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizerRight];    
    [recognizerRight release];

}

- (IBAction)swipeLeft{
    //NSLog(@"Swipe left");
    if(pager.currentPage < pager.numberOfPages - 1){
        pager.currentPage = (pager.currentPage + 1 );
        [self pagerValueChanged];
    }

}

- (IBAction)pagerValueChanged 
{
    NSData* imgData = [images objectAtIndex:pager.currentPage];
    UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imgData];
    imageView.image = img;

    //NSLog(@"img width: %f, img height: %f", img.size.width, img.size.height);

    [img release];
}
```

I have paging control and other controls too in my code, but you probably don't need those

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using array enumeration. The following code will take a scroll view that you have already configured and add image views to it for all the objects in your array. It will also dynamically adjust the content size of the scroll view based on the count of the array.

```
[myMutableArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:idx]]];
    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(myScrollView.frame.size.width * idx, myScrollView.frame.origin.y, myScrollView.frame.size.width, myScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [myScrollView addSubview:myImageView];
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake((myScrollView.frame.size.width * idx) + myScrollView.frame.size.width, myScrollView.frame.size.height)];
}];
```